# Freshly Installed Apache-Tomcat on the AWS server, how can I access from outside world

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, dns

I have installed an App with Apache tomcat on AWS ec2 instance. I am able to access the tomcat url (which is server_name:8080/BOE/BI) from the AWS instance on Win2016. Also I installed IIS on the server.

Now what are the configurations I need to do to on AWS ec2 instance to access the URL from outside the AWS instance like from my personal PC.

I also tried disabling the firewalls, it did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/using-network-security.html). This will allow you to open up ports on your EC2 instance from the outside world.